# Error series vanishes on resizing window

Tags: c#-4.0, teechart

Following plot has a error series Series2 which is not displayed on this chart, but legends says about its existence. This series needs to be displayed with minimum y value as infinity. But, Tee chart doesn't have any provision to specify -Infinity directly. So, we defined a huge negative number instead; which is significantly larger than the y axis to give an appearance of -Infinity to the user. But, if the chart area becomes too small compared to this huge negative number, the series (here series2) vanishes entirely.

Here is the series data used - 
Series2 Points:

X-------------------->>Bar-------------------->>Std. Error

1432 --------->> -50.19380462 ----------->> 50.20619538

1797 ---------->> 50.19380462 ----------->> 50.20619538

2164 ---------->>  -50.19380462  ----------->>  50.20619538

2529 --------->> -50.19380462    ----------->>  50.20619538

[image]

Can anyone please help to resolve this issue?

Thanking you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next release of TeeChart for .NET includes support for extended Axis ranges, from Double.MinValue to Double.MaxValue, and goes some way further to handle infinite value issues. That doesn't say for sure that it will resolve the issue you describe here. If you are able to send Steema Support a sample project that shows the issue we can test it with the new release.